# How do I convert the timestamp of Facebook "Message" object

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I apologize if this turns out to be a really dumb question. I am reading a [message object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/message) through the Facebook messenger API, using Flask in Python.

I first extract the timestamp after reading in the JSON object

```
# read the JSON from Flask "request" object    
input_json = request.get_json() 
# extract the timestamp
ts = input_json["entry"][0]["messaging"][0]["timestamp"]
```

Then I try to convert the result into a human-readable date format using `datetime` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)), figuring this was a Unix timestamp, but it returns a *ValueError: year is out of range*.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ts)))
```

Now turns out the specific message has a timestamp *1504129573859*, which is in the future, when I check e.g. [here](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/).

The same error occurs when I feed it the timestamp given in the documentation (link above), which is *1458692752478* so I figure it's not an issue with my input parsing. I could not find anything regarding this on here or the FB docs and am grateful for any help!

- Which time format is this, and how can I convert it to a `datetime` object?
- Or is there something wrong with my approach / thinking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can convert fb's timestamp to python timestamp at first:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts/1000.0)
```

Comment: No need to cast it to a int - you lose precision. In Py2 use `ts/1000.0` (or `from __future__ import division`)

Comment: Thank you sir, that totally solved it! Is there any specific reason for this * 1000 business?

Comment: Because facebook returns a timestamp in `milliseconds` since epoch. and `fromtimestamp()` takes `seconds`

Comment: You may find that it is in `utc` so you may need `datetime.utcfromtimestamp()`

Comment: @AChampion that makes a lot of sense, thanks for the helpful comments!

Comment: No need to cast to int in c#. I used it in milliseconds.